# Merge columns of different length and missing values in R

Tags: r, csv, boxplot

I have a simple problem, honestly I have tried to find an answer. I really did.

I have a bunch of .csv files that have been imported into R data frames

I would like to take a specific column (with a common name) from each data frame, merge it into a single data frame with the name of the data frame as the column name, and produce a boxplot using each column.

The columns are not of the same length and frequently contain NA's.

Example: Data frames (in which the first row is the header)

Data frame name `Tom`:

```
col1    col2 col3 col4
name1   33   44   55
name2   33   NA   55
name3   33   34   55
name4   33   24   55
```

Data frame name `Bob`:

```
col1    col2 col3 col4
name5   33   74   55
name6   33   NA   55
name7   33   32   55
```

Data frame name `Stu`:

```
col1    col2 col3 col4
name8   33   44   55
name9   33   11   55
name10  33   34   55
name11  33   24   55
name12  33   32   55
name13  33   24   5
name14  33   34   55
name15  33   24   5
```

Desired result

```
Tom  Bob  Stu
44   74   44
NA   NA   11 
34   32   34
24        24
          32
          24
          34
          24
```

So, taking "col3" (the column name is shared) from each data frame, and produce a new data frame of only the col3 data, each column to be named as the name of the data frame it came from...followed by producing a side-by-side boxplot of Tom, Bob and Stu (but I can probably work that out). It's OK to have NA's in the empty spaces in the desired result above.

Comment: It seems to me that it would make more sent to put the data into long format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic approach where I create a new combined data frame using `rbind`, after adding an identifier column to each of your 3 data frames. Note that you can also create a boxplot without first creating a single data frame.

```
Tom = read.table(header=TRUE,
text="col1    col2 col3 col4
name1   33   44   55
name2   33   NA   55
name3   33   34   55
name4   33   24   55")

Bob = read.table(header=TRUE,
text="col1    col2 col3 col4
name5   33   74   55
name6   33   NA   55
name7   33   32   55")

Stu = read.table(header=TRUE,
text="col1    col2 col3 col4
name8   33   44   55
name9   33   11   55
name10  33   34   55
name11  33   24   55
name12  33   32   55
name13  33   24   5
name14  33   34   55
name15  33   24   5")

# Add a new person identifier column to each data frame.
Tom$person = "Tom"
Bob$person = "Bob"
Stu$person = "Stu"

# Combine 3 data frames by row.
dat = rbind(Tom, Bob, Stu)

dat
#      col1 col2 col3 col4 person
# 1   name1   33   44   55    tom
# 2   name2   33   NA   55    tom
# 3   name3   33   34   55    tom
# 4   name4   33   24   55    tom
# 5   name5   33   74   55    bob
# 6   name6   33   NA   55    bob
# 7   name7   33   32   55    bob
# 8   name8   33   44   55    stu
# 9   name9   33   11   55    stu
# 10 name10   33   34   55    stu
# 11 name11   33   24   55    stu
# 12 name12   33   32   55    stu
# 13 name13   33   24    5    stu
# 14 name14   33   34   55    stu
# 15 name15   33   24    5    stu


boxplot(col3 ~ person, data=dat)

# This would also work, without rearranging the data:
boxplot(Tom[, "col3"], Bob[, "col3"], Stu[, "col3"])

# Save to pdf file.
pdf("boxplot_1.pdf", height=5, width=5)
boxplot(col3 ~ person, data=dat, main="Boxplot of three samples.", ylab="col3")
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks! That works fine and I can now extrapolate it to solve other issues I've been having. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Put you data.frames in a named list, `llist` from the `Hmisc` package is useful here

```
library(Hmisc)
data.list <- llist(Tom, Bob, Stu)
library(reshape2)
# get a long format version of col3
col3 <- melt(lapply(data.list, `[[`, 'col3'))
# the column `L1` contains the names Tom, Bob, Stu

library(ggplot2)
# create the boxplots

ggplot(col3, aes(x=L1, y= value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. I'm trying to do it with a minimum of non-standard packages but I'll try this too.

Comment: `Hmisc`, `ggplot2` and `reshape2` are all very useful, well maintained non-core packages.

Comment: True but this is for a program which may, hopefully, be used by people even less competent than me, so I'm keeping it simple for now.